# Activity crashing when setting non-view fragment listener on rotation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have an `Activity` that dynamically adds two fragments.  One is a hidden (no view) `Fragment` that has `setRetainInstance(true)` and handles the interface to my Database Handler. Its purpose is to start the `AsyncTask` for getting data out of the database and listen for the Database Handler to give its results back.  It will then hand the data back to the `Activity` via another listener.  The `Activity` will then hand the data to the display `Fragment` which has a `ListView` within and will display accordingly.

Activity:  NOT a FRAGMENT ACTIVITY

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 

public class Workout_Search_Display_Activity  extends Activity { 
private final String search_string = "SEARCH_STRING"; 
private final String search_type = "SEARCH_TYPE"; 
private String Search_String = ""; 
private String Search_Type = ""; 
private Workout_Search_Holder_Fragment SearchHolder; 
private Workout_Search_Display_Fragment search_display_fragment; 
private Workout_Search_Activity_Listener WSAL; 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    Search_String =  getIntent().getStringExtra(search_string); 
    Search_Type = getIntent().getStringExtra(search_type); 

    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        SearchHolder = Workout_Search_Holder_Fragment.newInstance(Search_String, Search_Type); 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() 
                .add(android.R.id.content, SearchHolder).commit(); 
        search_display_fragment = Workout_Search_Display_Fragment.newInstance(); 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() 
                .add(android.R.id.content, search_display_fragment).commit; 
    } //added too try to fix// else 
     //added to try to fix// SearchHolder = (Workout_Search_Holder_Fragment) getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("search_holder");

    WSAL = new Workout_Search_Activity_Listener() { 
        public void NothingFound() { 
            search_display_fragment.no_data(); 

            } 

        public void results_found(ArrayList<Search_Results_Holder> results) { 
        search_display_fragment.is_data(); 
            search_display_fragment.handover_data(results); 

        } 

       }; 
SearchHolder.setListener(WSAL); 
  } 
}
```

Fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment; 
import android.os.AsyncTask; 
import android.os.Build; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log; 

public class Workout_Search_Holder_Fragment extends Fragment implements DatabaseHelper.Workout_Search_Listener { 
private String Search_String = ""; 
private String Search_Type = ""; 
private final static String search_string = "SEARCH_STRING"; 
private final static String search_type = "SEARCH_TYPE"; 
private Workout_Search_Activity_Listener listener; 

protected static Workout_Search_Holder_Fragment newInstance( 
        String Search_String, String Search_Type) { 
    Workout_Search_Holder_Fragment f = new Workout_Search_Holder_Fragment(); 

    Bundle args = new Bundle(); 

    args.putString(search_string, Search_String); 
    args.putString(search_type, Search_Type); 
    f.setArguments(args); 
    return f; 
} 

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 
    setRetainInstance(true); 
    Search_String = getArguments().getString(search_string, null); 
    Search_Type = getArguments().getString(search_type, null); 
    sendSearch(); 
} 

public Workout_Search_Activity_Listener getListener() { 
    return listener; 
} 


public void setListener(Workout_Search_Activity_Listener listener) { 
    this.listener = listener; 
} 
private void sendSearch() { 
    DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getSearchResultsAsync( 
            Search_String, Search_Type, this); 


} 

static public <T> void executeAsyncTask(AsyncTask<T, ?, ?> task, T... params) { 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > +Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) { 
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params); 

    } else { 
        task.execute(params); 
    } 
} 
@Override 
public void return_no_results_found() { 
    listener.NothingFound(); 
} 
@Override 
public void return_search_results(ArrayList<Search_Results_Holder> results) { 
    Log.v("workout search holder fragment", "results found in fragment, handing off to activity");   
    listener.results_found(results); 

   }     
}
```

My issue is:  When rotating the screen, my code crashes with a Null Pointer Exception on the SetListener for the Search_Hander in the Activity.  If I change the `Activity` to a `FragmentActivity` and use the `SupportFragmentManager`....none of this is an issue...all works correctly with just those quick changes (something about the now-deprecated `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` being overridden by the `SupportFragmentManager` and it handles everything for you).

In trying to fix this, I kept it as an `Activity`, but put in `SearchHolder = (Workout_Search_Holder_Fragment) getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("search_holder")` as part of the `else` if the `R.id.Content` wasn't `null` and gave the `Fragment` a tag when I initially set it up if the `R.id.Content` WAS `null`.  See the commented out code above.  This worked, but created another issue where the `onActivityCreated` started again and launched my AsyncTask when I didn't want it to.  I can't send or check variables in the `savedInstanceState` bundle to the fragment, as it is null due to the `setRetainInstance(true)`.  I know I'm doing something wrong, but can't get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is two fold:

1. I needed to manually attach the `Fragments`, this I knew.
2. I was executing my `AsyncTask` in the wrong area.  This I didn't know.

It turns out that my `AsyncTask` was re-executing as `OnActivityCreated` is called again, even if `saveInstanceState(true)` is set.  BUT, `onCreate` is not.  By just changing the calling method to `onCreate`, i ensured that the `AsyncTask` was called only once, as it won't be called again upon `Activity` recreation.    In the Activity, I still needed to reset my holders for both fragments upon testing if `R.id.content` was NOT null by grabbing those fragments that matched the tags...and this was part of the answer that Dinash gave.

```
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        SearchHolder = Workout_Search_Holder_Fragment.newInstance(
                Search_String, Search_Type, false);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, SearchHolder, "searchholder")
                .commit();
        search_display_fragment = Workout_Search_Display_Fragment
                .newInstance();
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, search_display_fragment,
                        "displayholder").commit();
    } else {
        Log.v("activity", "non-null holder");
    SearchHolder = (Workout_Search_Holder_Fragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag("searchholder");
    search_display_fragment = (Workout_Search_Display_Fragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag("displayholder");
    }
```

`FragmentManager` required me to test for the content being null in addition to reattaching the `Fragments` on my own, which is something that the `FragmentSupportManager` did NOT required.  This also has the effect of requireing me to save the ArrayList that I am using for the `ListView`...again...`FragmentSupportManager` did all this on its own without prodding from me.

I still am curious as to why this behavior is different for the `FragmentActivity` as it seems to take care of ALL of this for me and required minimum amount of effort/code to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

> add(ANDROID.R.id.content, SearchHolder)

while adding your fragment, instead try

> add(ContainerID, SearchHolder,"search_holder"), which makes sure that your fragment is added with a tag "search_holder"

then as you did in else part try getting that fragment object by calling

> findFragmentByTag() 
>    method

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I originally tried all of that.... It worked but now the fragment calls the onActivityCreated when i grab the old fragment in the Else part. Should i be doing my AsyncTask from OnCreate so it doesnt get called twice (as OnCreate doesnt get called again if i retain the fragment, but OnActivityCreated does). My only concern is that the task may complete before my listener is set in the activity. Funny thing is that NONE of this is needed at all if I use FragmenyActivity with SupportFragmentManager...why the behavior difference?

Comment: You want the async task to be executed only once? Why can't you set the listener before committing the transaction so that listener will be available when you have the async task executed from the oncreate of the fragment? Am wondering on you say "NONE is needed when using FragmentActivity with SupportFragmentManager", i have not come across such behaviour.

Comment: Just once no matter how many time the screen rotates...just once upon activity creation.  The holder fragment is used to allow the activity to have a hold on the running background code in case of a rotation.  The holder fragments only responsibility is to start the sql query in my DataHelper (another separate class extended from opensqlhelper)and to pass the results it receives to the activity.  The activity then passes those results to the display fragment to display.

Comment: Posted the answer below, but I still wanted to thank you for your help and input.